# How to INSERT text (HTML markup) containing special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What I want to do - I have multiple templates - `.doc` files converted to `HTML` I have a table in my database where I want to keep this `HTML` markup. I'm trying to `INSERT` the data directly from `SQL Server Management Studio` and the query is pretty simple by itself:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HtmlTemplates] VALUES (20, 'here goes the HTML markup')
```

But in my `HTML` markup I have single quotes, double quotes and other special characters and if I'm going to escape them manually one by one it would be a lot of wasted time. I wonder is there any way to directly insert this markup?

Comment: I'd write a little program in any language, using parameters

Comment: If this is being done from an application (.net, php, coldfusion, etc), use query parameters.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yeah, the whole point is if there's anyway to do this using `SQL Server Management studio`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use SSMS but don't mind reading from a flat file, you could always use the [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command.

SO Example: [How to read a Text file using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502213/how-to-read-a-text-file-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a HTML Encode, do a URL encode with https://www.urlencoder.org/

this will return you a string of characters that you can use to Insert from Management Studio. The only challenge this brings is that you will be required to decode the message later.