# Reading number of rows in a text file through SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, localhost

I have a stream that I convert into a string and then write to a text file (or csv, doesn't really matter) on C:. Now I want to access that file (C:\InterfaceFiles\Requirements.txt) and determine the number of rows in that file. Can SQL do that, or do I need to use another command?

edit: Went with @Malte R 's solution in the comments.

```
string[] filearray = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\InterfaceFiles\\" + query);
count = filearray.Length;
Console.WriteLine(query + " row count = " + count);
```

Comment: You could use ´File.ReadAllLines()´, which returns an array, which you can check the length of.

Comment: SQL can do that: see it [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12502435/4556142

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like you know a bit about reading files, and handling exceptions(much recommended) but this is the while loop I would use for that

```
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: Check my comment, a simpler solution^

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the text file via the ADO.Net ODBC Provider using the Microsoft Text Driver. See [Connecting to a Text file using ADO.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ConnectODBCText11262005070206AM/ConnectODBCText.aspx).

That said, you are better off reading the file using a StreamReader:

```
using System.IO;

int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```