# SQL Server : Query using data from a file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a query in SQL Server, where I have a particular number of values stored individually on separate lines in a text file, and I need to run a query in SQL server to check if a value in a column of the table matches any one of the value stored in the txt file.

How should I go about doing this ?

I am aware of how to formulate various types of queries in SQL Server, just not sure how to run a query that is dependent on a file for its query parameters.

**EDIT :**

**Issue 1 :** I am not doing this via a program since the query that I need to run traverses over 7 million datapoints which results in the program timing out before it can complete, hence the only alternative I have left is to run the query in SQL Server itself without worrying about the timeout.

**Issue 2 :** I do not have admin rights to the database that I am accessing which is why there is no way I could create a table, dump the file into it, then perform a query by joining those tables.

Thanks.

Comment: If a program is going to be invoking this query, why not have the program take care of parsing the text file?  That would simplify things.

Comment: @David : Check my edits to the question, I've explained the issues that I'm facing.

Comment: A query that hits 7 million datapoints????

Comment: @SeanLange : Yes, a query that has to go through close to 7 million data-points to compare with the values in a file and then displays the result.

Comment: Stark..table variables, temp tables, etc. run in the context of the thread (i.e. from SSMS, Access pass-through query, ODBC client. etc.). You do not need a permanent table. You'll need permission to run any sort of query, so BULK INSERT into one of these types should be fine.

Comment: @DanielG : So even if I do not have permissions to create tables, I could create a temp table and run my query ?

Comment: *"which results in the program timing out before it can complete*" > Obvious answer is obvious: increase the timeout...

Comment: I have never seen a system with anywhere near that many datapoints....unless by datapoints you possible number of rows. Regardless this is entirely off topic to your question. One suggestion I haven't seen anybody mention is OPENROWSET. You can use that along with a format file to directly query a text file.

Comment: @TT. : By program, I meant it's a web application, and it's generally unadvisable to increase timeouts for web scripts.

Comment: @SeanLange : Any value in a cell in a table is a datapoint by definition, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, Stark. The creation of the table variable, or temp table, is running in the security context of the thread, and destroyed immediately when the SPID ends. Once the table variable is populated, you can LEFT JOIN to it on the fields you are checking for, and use a WHERE condition of Field IS NOT NULL (or IS NULL, depending on your logic). I'd use a table variable. You may also want to create an index on the table variable on the field in question. 7M rows is not a lot really, but the join could be expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use BULK INSERT and a temp table. Once in the temp table, you can parse the values. This is likely not the exact answer you need, but based on your experience, I'm sure you could tweak as needed.

Thanks...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

USE Your_DB;

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.t (
    i int, 
    n varchar(10),
    d decimal(18,4),
    dt datetime
    );
GO


BULK INSERT dbo.t
    FROM 'D:\import\data.txt'
    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502213/how-to-read-a-text-file-using-t-sql

Comment: @DanielG : For this BULK INSERT to work, does the file I am uploading need to be on the same server as the database ? Or can I upload a file from my local machine as well ?

Comment: The file needs to be "reachable" by SQL Server itself. That could be a UNC (\\MACHINE\DRIVE\File.txt) or path to a locally accessible drive. I'm not sure about your scenario, but you can FTP or FileCopy the file first. Maybe also consider using TABLE TYPE, and pass in a Structured Data Type as a parameter to the stored procedure. That would involve parsing the file locally first into a DataTable. If the process happens infrequently, maybe a combination of pushing the file to an FTP site, and a SQL job to pull down locally using a SQL job.  The size of the file/data may affect the decision.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of approaches.

Mine would be to import the file to a table, do the comparison with a regular SQL query, and then delete the file-data table if you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bulk import the data from text file into a temporary table.
2. Execute the query to do the comparison between your actual physical table & temporary table.