# Re - Purpose Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Ok So I want to import Sales orders from Flat file or Excel via an FTP connection . I have a copy of the Sales import SP that our ERP uses but i want to re-Purpose it to read a file direct from a folder location rather than importing it  through  the ERP UI . I'm not sure how to go about doing this

I have read about flat file and bulk inserts but I dont think this is the correct route , I have included the available SP I have

I would to like to find a way to re-purpose this SP , I have not added the SP as its a bit  large

Comment: So basically, if I understand you correctly, you are asking how to read a text file from _Transact SQL_. If so, perhaps this _Stack Overflow_ [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502213/how-to-read-a-text-file-using-t-sql) may help?

Comment: I would like to import the flat file and pass it though an available SP - something like the below                                                                                                     `CREATE TABLE #TEXTFILE_1(
    FIELD1 varchar(100) ,
    FIELD2 varchar(100) ,
    FIELD3 varchar(100) ,
    FIELD4 varchar(100));

BULK INSERT #TEXTFILE_1 FROM 'C:\STUFF.TXT'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =' | ',ROWTERMINATOR =' \n')

/*You now have your bulk data*/

insert  into  wsp_SalesOrdersImport_JL_EDI_JJC
from #TEXTFILE_1 txt

drop table #TEXTFILE_1`

Comment: Yep - that looks like the way to do it - what issue are you experiencing when trying this?

Comment: To be honest . I have not tried it . But if I can pass data through a  SP in this way I will give it a go